# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException fps, gameconfig [Closed/Cerrado]

Tags: java

Busco ayuda con un error como el del título, *"java.lang.NullPointerException"*, por lo que tengo entendido este error ocurre cuando se usa un método de un objeto nulo no? Pues ando usando un objeto que no es nulo (lo inicializo) pero aun así me sale el error. Aquí el exception:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at de.mrbunny.midnight.util.FPS.initFps(FPS.java:44)
>   at de.mrbunny.engine.GameConfig.init(GameConfig.java:22)
>   at de.mrbunny.midnight.TheMidnight.<init>(TheMidnight.java:17)
>   at de.Start.main(Start.java:11)
> ```

Aquí el código de las class:

```
FPS: 

public static int fps = 0;
public static int ups = 0;

private boolean started = false;
private int maxFps = 60;
    
public void initFps(Window window) {
  
  final int NS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000;
  final byte UPS_OBJECTIVE = 30;
  final double NS_PER_UPDATE = NS_PER_SECOND / UPS_OBJECTIVE;

  long referenceUpdate = System.nanoTime ();
  long referenceContainer = System.nanoTime ();

  System.out.println("Dentro del inicio de los fps");

  double transcurrentTime;
  double delta = 0;

  while(started) {
    long startLoop = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("a");

    transcurrentTime = startLoop - referenceUpdate;
    referenceUpdate = startLoop;

    delta += transcurrentTime / NS_PER_UPDATE;

    while (delta >= 1) {
      Start.getGame().update();
      delta--;
    }

    Start.getGame().draw();

    if(System.nanoTime () - referenceContainer > NS_PER_SECOND) {
      window.setTitle ("TheMidnight || UPS:" + ups + " || FPS: " + fps);
      fps = 0;
      ups = 0;
      referenceContainer = System.nanoTime ();
    }

    while(fps > maxFps) {
      fps = maxFps - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

//setters i getters
La verdad se me hace un poco raro ya que bueno, en ningún a de las Class he visto un objeto nulo o algo entonces agradecería la ayuda

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 44? Es posible que `getGame` devuelva o `window` sea null. Pero como no sé cuál línea es la 44 no puedo responder con certeza.

Comment: Coincido con Mateo, **initFps(Window window)** esta es la linea que lanza el error, se está invocando a **initFps** con un Window nulo, debes ver la parte de tu aplicación que hace la llamada y corregirla.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: @Mateo, la linea 44 es la linea **Start.getGame().draw();**

Comment: @MarcePuente gracias.

Comment: Entonces `getGame()` debe devolver null.

Answer (score 0):

Si la linea 44 es la linea Start.getGame().draw()

Quiere decir que dicha propiedad no ha sido inicializada, no tiene valor inicial, por lo q es nulo por default.

Tal vez quieras poner la Clase Start, para complementar la respuesta, e incluso la Clase Game.